# Giving unable to convert String to Category Error

Tags: c#, filter, combobox

I can't seem to be able to filter my list box with my combobox, though the text filter works fine. How can I fix the problem of being unable to convert String to Category?

Part of: StaffListView.xaml

```
StaffController sc = (StaffController)Application.Current.FindResource("staffcontroller");
public StaffListView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StaffController sc = (StaffController)Application.Current.FindResource("staffcontroller");
}

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        //too much going on i think it sees the () as a method because of the ToString
        sc.FilterBy(comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show("Dropdown list used to select: " + e.AddedItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Part of StaffControler:

```
public void FilterBy(Category currCategoryFilter)
{
    var selected = from Staff s in MasterStaffListBasic
                   where currCategoryFilter == Category.All || s.StaffCategory == currCategoryFilter
                   select s;
    ViewableStaffList.Clear();
    selected.ToList().ForEach(ViewableStaffList.Add);
}
```

EDIT:
Also just to clarify Category is a public enum defined in the controller

Comment: Don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed a string to the `FilterBy` method which accepts a category as a parameter. You should pass the `comboBox.SelectedItem` but cast it to `Category` like this:

```
entersc.FilterBy(comboBox.SelectedItem as Category);
```

Based on your edit that you said *Category is a public enum* you should pass it like this:

```
entersc.FilterBy((Category) comboBox.SelectedItem);
```

Or if you still want to use [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator:

```
entersc.FilterBy(comboBox.SelectedItem as Category? ?? (Category) 0);
```

Because the `as` operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type.